# How to - Split an int into two ints?

Tags: c#, int

Say you have:

```
Int32 I = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
```

So you enter 'a' into the console, which would make the output "97"
How could I split that output into two separate integers or an array? So, "9" and "7" instead of "97"

I'm coding in C#, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here, but if you really want to do this, you could convert it to a string then create a character array like so:

```
Int32 I = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
var chars = I.ToString().ToCharArray();
```

This will give you a char array with a 9, and a 7 in it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, someone else gave that answer also, and it works :)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I was watching some TV, so I was a bit slow on the draw. :)

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to convert the number to a string and then use the `ToCharArray` method to get each digit as a individual character.

```
string str = i.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
char[] digits = str.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: Those aren't integers as requested in the question

Comment: @James: You want to be more specific - those aren't integers.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it back into a string, and then use linq to project onto an integer array:

```
            string a = "a";
            Int32 I = Convert.ToChar(a);
            string b = Convert.ToString(I);
            var c = b.ToCharArray();
            var d = c.Select(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.ToString()));
            Int32[] I2 = d.ToArray();
```